# Is it possible to add a video instead of an image on react-native-snap-carousel?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video, react-native-snap-carousel

I'm currently using react-native-snap-carousel's `<ParallaxImage />` component. Is it possible to extend it to parallax video's? If there is no way to do that on react-native-snap-carousel please tell me about any alternative methods that can be used.

Comment: did you try it yet?

Comment: I have no clue... the `<ParallaxImage />` component only takes an image uri as a prop